# How to use Python to download a CSV file from a website

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I use Python to connect to the website https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener and press the <kbd>Download CSV</kbd> button to obtain a list of all NASDAQ symbols.

I used the below code but nothing happened when I run it. Could you please provide me guidelines to correct my codes. It's not clear to me how to see on google Chrome how to locate Python for downloading the csv file and code correctly the csv_url_extension? It's seems there is no button "Download CSV" in Google Chrome for Dev? Can you please provide me guidelines to correct the codes below :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# url of initial page with data
url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener"
# name of csv file where to store downloaded csv data
csv_file_name = "/Users/document/tickers_nasdaq.csv"


# get html content of initial page
html_data = requests.get(url=url) \
                .content
# generate Beautifulsoup object based on hrml content of initial page
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup=html_data)
# extract url extension of downloadable csv file
csv_url_extension = soup.find(attrs={'class': "path-node page-node- 
type-market-activity-page with-header-ads with-header-ads--loaded"}) \
                    .get(key='href')
# construct url of downloadable csv file
csv_url = "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener" + csv_url_extension
# get content of downloadable csv file and saving it to file
response = requests.get(url=csv_url)
if response.status_code == 200:
   with open(csv_file_name, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

Comment: Beautiful Soup is primarily used for parsing and navigating HTML and XML documents, but it does not provide a built-in mechanism for interacting with web pages or performing actions like clicking buttons. To interact with web pages and perform actions like clicking buttons, you can use a library like Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how:

```py
import csv

import requests

csv_url = "https://api.nasdaq.com/api/screener/stocks?tableonly=true&limit=25&offset=0&download=true"
headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.67",
}
data = requests.get(csv_url, headers=headers).json()['data']

columns = data['headers']
body = data['rows']

with open('stocks.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(columns)
    for item in body:
        writer.writerow(item.values())
```

Output:

A `.csv` file that looks like this:

[image]